# How to call a method after the space bar is pressed in a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Sorry for what is likely a simple question, but how can I call a method every time the space bar is pressed in a JTextArea? I have tried attaching a keylistener to the text area, but I wasn't able to get that to work. Thanks.

Comment: What does your keylistener code look like?

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with key bindings.

Answer (score 6):

Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

The tutorial has examples and you can find plenty of other examples in the forum.

When you create the custom Action that you want to execute you would extend TextAction.

Answer (score 4):

```
JTextArea jt=new JTextArea();

jt.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){ 

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke){ 

         if(ae.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
              //call your method
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: -1, just because something works doesn't mean it should be promoted. This approach was used in AWT applications when you didn't have a choice. For a long time members of the forum have been trying to promote the proper way to use Swing. As I mentioned in my earlier comment Swing was designed to be used with Key Bindings. Once you learn this Swing is much easier to use and customize.

Answer (score 0):

While @camickr has a good, simple solution which I have upvoted, a complex but more thorough option is to work with the `Document` associated with the `JTextArea`, and override it's `insertString()` method.  Sometimes you are already doing this, for example, to prevent letters from getting added to a numeric field.  The advantage is has over a KeyBinding is that it will also catch when the user *copies and pastes* into the JTextArea.  So, if the user copies and pastes "foo bar" into the area, a KeyBinding will not catch that (I'm pretty sure, am I wrong here?) and the Document technique will. e.g., very schematically:

```
@Override
public void insertString(int offset, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {
  if (str.contains(" "))
    callMySpecialSpaceMethod();
  super.insertString(offset, str, a);
}
```

As pointed out by @camickr, instead of directly subclassing and overriding Document.insertString(), one can set it's DocumentFilter instead.  ([favor Composition over Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).)  Unfortunately, it's a bit clunky with some casting, but here's the basic code:

```
((AbstractDocument)myTextArea.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {

    @Override
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {
        if (str.contains(" "))
            callMySpecialSpaceMethod();
        fb.insertString(offset, str, a);
    }

});
```

This is a lot more work that a KeyBinding so, unless you really need to be this thorough, or you are already doing this for another reason, the KeyBinding is simpler.  And it depends on your requirements - in your case, I don't think you care if they copy and paste.

Comment: There is no need to override the insertString() method of the Document. If you really want to do things at the Document level then you would use a `DocumentListener` or a `DocumentFilter` depending on the exact requirement.

Comment: You are right - using DocumentListener/Filter actually sounds very familiar.  Its been a while since I did this, but I wanted to mention the general Document concept.  When I get time I'll edit/update.  And, for this OP, your KeyBinding post is almost certainly the correct approach.